# Importing a certificate with "Import-PfxCertificate" results in an invalid cert

Tags: powershell, ssl, iis, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have a certificate (`.pfx`) that works fine when I import it using the GUI with (include all extended properites) checked.
If I import it without that checked, I can't use it in IIS.
If I try to import it via powershell (the end goal), I also can't use it in IIS.

When I try to use it in IIS, I get this error message:

> A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been
>   terminated.

I've tried a few methods for importing it, this is the most recent version of my script:

```
$certPassword = convertto-securestring 'thecertpasswordhere' -asplaintext -force
Import-PfxCertificate  $localFilePath -Password $certPassword
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make this work or what I can look into for more info?  I've had no luck searching so far.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tried to specify the certlocation?

Answer (score 1):

Verify the script is running with the appropriate credentials (i.e. `LOCAL SYSTEM`, etc.).

You can also try piping the certificate (*.pfx) as follows:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $localFilePath | Import-PfxCertificate -CertStoreLocation Cert:\LocalMachine\My -Password (ConvertTo-SecureString -String "thecertpasswordhere"  -Force -AsPlainText
```